# empty data field in response several posts crawled from a facebook public page

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use facebook graph api to scrape all the posts from a public page. After crawling over 5k posts from a specific page I get a response : **{"data":[]}** , so there is no cursor to move to the next page.

Any idea what might be the issue ? and is there a way to manage such a case and move to the next page?

here is how I construct my url:

`base = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10"
    node = "/"+ page_id + "/feed" 
    parameters = "?fields=from{id,name,first_name,last_name,birthday,email,gender,hometown,location,about,significant_other,timezone},\
                    place,message,created_time,name,id,shares,likes.limit(0).summary(true)"
    parameters += "&access_token=%s&limit=%s" %(access_token,rate_limit)
    if after_cursor:
        parameters +="&after={}".format(after_cursor)
    url = base + node + parameters`

Comment: Most likely the page is not public

Comment: It is , because the problem only occurs after retrieving thousands of posts